# On Windows, are there restrictions on extensions that can be used in PATHEXT?

Tags: windows, powershell, console

I am trying to set file associations on my Windows machine so that files with the extension `.script` run without needing the extension specified (much like `.bat`, `.ps1`, `.py` files).

I have set things up using the following batch file:

```
REG ADD HKCU\Environment /v PATHEXT /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%%PATHEXT%%;.script"
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\.script /ve /d "Script.File"
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\Script.File /ve /d "Script file with hashbang line"
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\Script.File\shell\open\command /ve /d "\"C:\WINDOWS\py.exe\" \"%%1\" %%*"
```

This *almost* works, but when I run a `.script` file, it runs in a new window, rather than in my current console session.

If I change the extension I have chosen to something shorter, like `.sf`, then it works fine.

Is there a limitation on file extensions which can be used in the console, that they have to be less than 3 characters, or something?

(In case it's relevant, this is on Windows 7, 64-bit).

**Update**: This only seems to happen in Powershell. Both CMD and TCC (TCC/LE) work as expected (the script is run in the console session).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a known bug in Powershell: https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/238550/power-shell-trimming-extension-to-3-characters-when-resolving-file-associations

From the bug report, it looks like MS don't intend to fix it :-(